# Collaborative settings on Adobe PDF embed API not working using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, adobe-embed-api, adobe-pdfservices

I was trying out the collaborative settings on the adobe pdf embed API using Reactjs. I created a separate SDKClient wherein all the constructors are placed. But still, the profile is set to "Guest".

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

This is what my code looks like:

ViewSDKClient.js

```
class ViewSDKClient {
    constructor() {
        this.readyPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (window.AdobeDC) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", () => {
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        });
        this.adobeDCView = undefined;
    }
    ready() {
        return this.readyPromise;
    }

    previewFile(divId, viewerConfig, url) {
        const config = {
            clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID, ///enter lient id here
        };
        if (divId) {
            config.divId = divId;
        }
        this.adobeDCView = new window.AdobeDC.View(config);
        const previewFilePromise = this.adobeDCView.previewFile(
            {
                content: {
                    location: {
                        url: url,
                    },
                },
                metaData: {
                    fileName: "Menu.pdf",
                    id: "6d07d124-ac85-43b3-a867-36930f502ac6",
                },
            },
            viewerConfig
        );
        return previewFilePromise;
    }

    previewFileUsingFilePromise(divId, filePromise, fileName) {
        this.adobeDCView = new window.AdobeDC.View({
            clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID, //enter Client id here
            divId,
        });
        this.adobeDCView.previewFile(
            {
                content: {
                    promise: filePromise,
                },
                metaData: {
                    fileName: fileName,

                },
            },
            {}
        );
    }

    registerSaveApiHandler() {
        const saveApiHandler = (metaData, content, options) => {
            console.log(metaData, content, options);
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    const response = {
                        code: window.AdobeDC.View.Enum.ApiResponseCode.SUCCESS,
                        data: {
                            metaData: Object.assign(metaData, {
                                updatedAt: new Date().getTime(),
                            }),
                        },
                    };
                    resolve(response);
                }, 2000);
            });
        };
        this.adobeDCView.registerCallback(
            window.AdobeDC.View.Enum.CallbackType.SAVE_API,
            saveApiHandler,
            {}
        );
    }

    registerEventsHandler() {
        const profile = {
            userProfile: {
                name: "John Doe",
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Doe",
                email: "gg@gg.com"
            }
        };

        this.adobeDCView.registerCallback(
            window.AdobeDC.View.Enum.CallbackType.GET_USER_PROFILE_API,
            (event) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    resolve({
                        code: window.AdobeDC.View.Enum.ApiResponseCode.SUCCESS,
                        data: profile
                    });
                });
            }
        );
        // this.adobeDCView.registerCallback(
        //     window.AdobeDC.View.Enum.CallbackType.EVENT_LISTENER,
        //     (event) => {
        //         console.log(event);
        //     },
        //     {
        //         enablePDFAnalytics: true,
        //     }
        // );
    }
}
export default ViewSDKClient;
```

Index.js

```
  const loadPDF = (url = "/WriterModule.pdf") => {
    const viewSDKClient = new ViewSDKClient();
    viewSDKClient.ready().then(() => {
      viewSDKClient.previewFile(
        "pdfDiv",
        {
          showAnnotationTools: true,
          showLeftHandPanel: false,
          showPageControls: true,
          showDownloadPDF: true,
          showPrintPDF: false,
          showDisabledSaveButton: false,
        },
        url
      );
      // viewSDKClient.registerCallback(
      //   ViewSDKClient.View.Enum.CallbackType.GET_USER_PROFILE_API,
      //   function () {
      //     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //       resolve({
      //         code: ViewSDKClient.View.Enum.ApiResponseCode.SUCCESS,
      //         // data: {
      //         //   name: "John Doe",
      //         //   firstName: "John",
      //         //   lastName: "Doe",
      //         //   email: "gg@gg.com"
      //         // }
      //         data: profile
      //       });
      //     });
      //   });
    });
  };

return(
   <div className="previewSection">
        <div
          className="filePreview full-window-div col-md-8"
          id="pdfDiv"
          onDocumentLoad={loadPDF(url)}
        ></div></div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to registerCallBack before calling adobeDCView.previewFile

```
this.adobeDCView = new window.AdobeDC.View(config);

this.registerUserProfile(profile);

const previewFilePromise = this.adobeDCView.previewFile(...
`
```